# Hibernate session scope in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, session-variables

My question is about hibernate session scope in Grails :

1. Is session bound to a spring transaction?
2. A new session is created whenever a new request is created?
3. Or session is bound to a thread?

Can this be explained?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions are bound to transactions since the active `PlatformTransactionManager` is a `HibernateTransactionManager`. But be aware that controller requests do *not* run in transactions - only services are automatically transactional. You should refactor controllers that write to the database to use services to do that work so it's properly transactional.

A new session is created for each request and bound to the thread by the `GrailsOpenSessionInViewInterceptor`. This helps to avoid lazy loading exceptions and other issues. The session is flushed and closed at the end of the thread.

The `ThreadLocal` is in `TransactionSynchronizationManager` if you're curious; you can call `TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(sessionFactory)` (use `def sessionFactory` to get access to the `SessionFactory`) to access the `SessionHolder` that holds the session.